# Tooltips in PDFs: are they possible?

Tags: php, pdf, tooltip, tcpdf

I'm using the [tcpdf PHP class](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) for creating PDFs. Is there any solution to add tooltips to links?

Answer (score 1):

Links itself cannot have tooltips. Viewers always show the URL.

But TCPDF can add "Annotations", which is the closest you can get to tooltips (but have to be assigned to a rectangle area instead of to text/paragraphs).
http://www.tecnick.com/pagefiles/tcpdf/doc/com-tecnick-tcpdf/TCPDF.html#methodAnnotation

You'll have to refer to the PDF specification. Section 8.4 and 8.4.5, and you are looking for "Popup".
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDFReference16.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so... seems the library doesn't support it, I even haven't met it in practice.

BTW they are called comments in PDF.